# Fixing big system font on some machines that is warping font in C++ program?

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-6

I have written a program (using Borland C++ builder) that works fine with normal default windows settings. But certain users have changed their systems to have a bigger font than normal (as in, they changed the windows theme or changed system settings to have the font bigger for bad eyesight, etc). This makes a lot of my text and fields wrap out of visibility. I remember having to conquer this issue years ago, but I can't seem to find any information on how to do it anymore -- not even where to start.

So the question is: Does anyone know how I can account for changing system fonts in my forms? Preferably, I'd love to just keep MY font size the same in-program size regardless of what the system wants, but I don't believe that's an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set each form's [Scaled](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TCustomActiveForm.Scaled) property to true. Each form will be resized according to the font scaling prevailing on the machine which shows the form.